# What type should I use to deserialize Legion ECS' World?

Tags: rust, serde

I want to deserialize the legion's world but don't know what type should I use. This is my deserializing function:

```
pub fn deserialize(path: &str) -> World {
    let registry = get_registry();
    
    let data_raw = pollster::block_on(load_string(path)).expect("Unable to load file");
    let mut deserializer = ron::from_str(data_raw.as_str()).expect("Unable to deserialze the file");
    
    let entity_serializer = Canon::default();
    
    registry.as_deserialize(&entity_serializer).deserialize(&mut deserializer).unwrap()
}
```

As you can see, the `deserializer` has no type.

This might not help but this is the serialization function that I implemented:

```
pub fn serialize(world: &World, path: &str) {
    let registry = get_registry();

    let entity_serializer = Canon::default();
    let serializable = world.as_serializable(any(), &registry, &entity_serializer);
    let ron = ron::to_string(
        &serializable
    ).expect("Cannot Serialize World!");
    let mut file = File::create(path).expect("Unable to create file");
    file.write_all(ron.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write it to the file");
}
```

I'm using [serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde) and [ron](https://crates.io/crates/ron).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deserialize` method in question comes from [`DeserializeSeed` trait](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.123/serde/de/trait.DeserializeSeed.html#tymethod.deserialize), so its argument have to be something implementing [`Deserializer`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.123/serde/trait.Deserializer.html). In case of `ron`, the type to use is [`ron::Deserializer`](https://docs.rs/ron/latest/ron/de/struct.Deserializer.html) (`&mut ron::Deserializer`, to be precise), which can be created with `Deserializer::from_str`.

Therefore, this code should work:

```
pub fn deserialize(path: &str) -> World {
    let registry = get_registry();
    
    let data_raw = pollster::block_on(load_string(path)).expect("Unable to load file");
    let mut deserializer = ron::Deserializer::from_str(data_raw.as_str()).expect("Unable to deserialze the file");
    
    let entity_serializer = Canon::default();
    
    registry.as_deserialize(&entity_serializer).deserialize(&mut deserializer).unwrap()
}
```